# TWIG: is it possible to have two filters or variable in variable?

Tags: twig

I want to do following

```
{% set checkicon = '<a id="{{ participant.id }}">' %}

<td>{{ checkicon | raw }}</td>
```

It doesnt word because twig variable in twig variable-definition is not possible. i heard about doing somthing like this

```
<td>{{ checkicon | replace({ '{{ participant.id }}': participant.id }) }}</td>
```

but now i have the problem that i want to add the raw-filter too. is it possible to add two filters to a twig variable? didnt found anything about that on net.

ty in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The `~` token is a concatenation for strings.

```
{% set checkicon = '<a id="' ~ participant.id ~ '">' %}
```